# How to access an Xml file from the Bin Directory for a Web API app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, appdomain, httpcontext

I've tried these options:

```
var resourcePath = "data.xml";
Application files are located in: c:/MyApp/bin/Release.
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory refers to "c:/MyApp" folder.
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath refers to "c:/MyApp/bin/Release" folder.
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(resourcePath) refers to http://www.domain.com/MyApp/data.xml
```

Only the PrivateBinPath works but by definition it can contain multiple bin directories so maybe I shouldn't be using this.

how's the standard approach for a Web API app to access a file in the Bin folder?

Comment: Standard dictates to have data files in APP_DATA folder not in BIN folder. Could you explain why you need this file in that folder?

Comment: yes I agree but this is a legacy app with asp.net 3.5. Regardless, how'd you access the file after being copied in the bin folder?

Comment: Did you try `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin", "data.xml")`?

Comment: Many thanks, yes worked :)

Answer (score 5):

If the BIN folder is a direct subfolder of your root site then

```
string resourceFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin", "data.xml");
```

should give you the dedidered path (and works also if you move your app on an external hosting site). Of course, being BIN a protected folder you should be sure to have the required permissions to read or write files in this path.